# MS Botframework - Builder.Prompts.Choice - How to respond if user types something not in the list?

Tags: botframework

In "builder.Prompts.choice", how do you capture user response, if user enters a choice not in the choice list, how do you capture the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is this

```
choice(session: Session, prompt: string | string[] | IMessage | IIsMessage, choices: string | Object | string[], options?: IPromptOptions): void
```

So you could do this

```
builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which fruit?", "apple|orange|peach", "Sorry I did not understand that!")
```

[Botframework Ref](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.prompts.html#choice)

Comment: Not working for me- `builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Choose","a|b|c", "Sorry"`' , showing a blank msg from bot in Emulator

Answer (score 1):

using `builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'Choose:', 'a|b|c', {retryPrompt:'Sorry'});` works for me.

edit: Just reread the original question. This doesn't capture the user's response, but it does allow you to alter the reprompt message.

Answer (score -1):

its work for me capture the user response "session.message.text".